# validating data after transaction and rolling back if necessary

Tags: javascript, transactions, indexeddb

My question concerns validating data for consistency between object stores after a transaction has completed and rolling back that transaction if the validation fails and/or salvaging the data in another manner. The primary concern is catching data errors generated through writing portions of the  database to disk and populating the database with data from disk.

My specific scenario is that one object store contains data for a pointer that holds the key paths of all the data objects in nearly all of the other object stores and coordinates the display and use of those data objects.

After data is read from a text file and used to populate the database and the write transaction completes, I'd like to validate that the pointer data and object store data are consistent by at least confirming that the counts match and, if possible, that all the key paths in the pointer have a match in each object store. I don't want the pointer pointing to a key path that no longer exists in the database; and I don't want a data object disappearing from the database uncaught when reading or writing to a text file.

Apart from the user deliberately tampering with the text file or a coding oversight, the only reasons an inconsistency would possibly ever occur is some type of hiccup in the writing to the database or the reading from the database when the text file was created. The purpose of the validation isn't to catch coding errors or file tampering but only to ensure that the data got to where it is supposed to be and is consistent. So, it's checking that the browser did what it said it did. There should be no coding errors; and file tampering will almost certainly cause far greater problems that will be caught elsewhere and stop the program.

Perhaps, there are three questions here.

1. Can a validation be performed within a transaction.oncomplete function, such that if the validation fails the transaction can be rolled back by using transaction.abort or something like that if there are other options? Or is it too late to roll back after the transaction completes? I think, in my case, the equivalent of rolling back the transaction can be performed manually, so to speak, if it's not possible to rollback a completed transaction, since it is known what the user attempted to do.
2. Ignoring file tampering by the user and coding errors, is it overkill to confirm that a completed transaction resulted in the data expected?
3. If it is reasonable to do so, can you share your recommendations or suggestions concerning how best to accomplish the scenario below?

I'd like to be able to inform the user that an error occurred in writing the data from the file to the database and to try it again; and, if it errors a second time, then give the user the abililty to salvage the data. Of course, I want to check the result on the read side before the file is written to disk also.

For example, a message could be displayed stating that Study Module 5 is missing Data Object 32.  Even if data object 32 cannot be recovered, the pointer can be modified to no longer point to it and the user will know that module 5 needs reviewed because it's going to skip from 31 to 33 and make no sense when it is run.  Other things can be done also that are specific to this program when such an error occurs.  For example, each module must pass a validation step before it can be run.  If a database error occurs in a particular module, then the validation status can be programmatically changed to false, rendering the module unable to be run until it is re-validated.

A user can spend several hours building a single study module, so it is important that they are able to save the module to disk and restore it without losing their work.  I'm assuming what I have referred to as a database hiccup is extremely rare, but if it were to occur, I don't want the user to lose the entire portfolio of study modules, but rather, to be able to salvage as much of it as possible and independently from within the program.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. transactions can be aborted, but not after completing
2. yes, overkill
3. write tests that make assertions about each operation. if you can prove each atomic operation completes correctly, then you can infer that the data in aggregate is in the correct state after several operations

if you are worried about lost work, save data in an incompleted state. just store a 'completed' boolean along with each row. periodically save with completed = false (or = incomplete whatever). at real save time, save a row with completed = true, then after that, delete the incompletes

Comment: Thanks. Just to make sure I understand, as an example, if an open cursor is expected to return 10,000 data objects to be converted to string and saved in a text file, if the transaction completes then there's no need to confirm that 10,000 were actually received? The browser can be counted on to "never" fail? Because, if only 9,999 are extracted, the pointer and object store won't be consistent and the read of that text file may fail causing the user to be unable to recover their work on their own. I'm not disagreeing, but just want to be sure to what extent the browser can be relied upon.

Comment: Don't know. I think it is reliable but I don't have evidence other than empirical